# Desativar Scroll com menu aberto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um menu com width 100% e height 100%, no qual uso um botão pra abri-lo e fecha-lo (no estilo hamburger). Mas quando ele abre o meu site ainda fica scrollando por trás dele. Quero saber como posso desativar o scroll do site quando o menu estiver aberto, e desativar quando fechar o menu.

Comment: Tiago, acredito que você quiz dizer offcanvas (estilo hamburger?), você pode simplemente colocar uma div de overlay sobre o conteudo, desativar o overflow, etc... em todo caso será bem vindo o HTML da pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi direito, mas pode ser que isto resolva:

Você pode adicionar um evento `scroll` por jQuery. Quando a pessoa rolar a página ele verifica se o menu está aberto. Se está aberto, ele força o `scrollTop` sempre **zero** (topo).

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkodmu2s/

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou. Apenas uma resalva. O script tá levando o scroll pro topo quando menu visível, ok, ótimo! Mas não há como desativar o scroll quando menu visível? Pois se estou na metade do site, e abro o menu e tento scrollar ele leva o site para o topo, e isso me incomoda um pouco.

Comment: Sim. Dai dá para salvar a posição da barra quando o menu é aberto, dai aplica-se esse valor quando a pessoa tenta rolar a página. Fiz aqui como ficaria: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkodmu2s/4/

Comment: cara, no seu teste tá dando certo, mas no meu não. Pode ver se tem algo errado no meu código? segue https://jsfiddle.net/rg3938yx/ @Ricardo

Comment: É que você esqueceu de setar a variável do valor do scroll. Tenta assim: https://jsfiddle.net/rg3938yx/1/

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, Ricardo!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda :))))

Comment: de nada :D @TiagoP.C

Answer (score -2):

O Scroll pode ser controlado por CSS:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
 body, html { 
     overflow: hidden; 
 }
```

Comment: isso não responde minha pergunta nem me ajuda a achar alguma solução.

Comment: Para achar uma solução preciso ver o que tem feito até o momento. Enquanto isso veja se isso te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily